# library and include paths, ~/lib and ~/include?

Tags: linux, unix, shared-libraries, static-libraries

What is the canonical path for a custom library and include files? I thought of either /usr/local/lib + /usr/local/include or ~/lib ~/include. To me the latter looks a better option, since the former are managed by the distribution's package manager and it is best not to interfere.. Though I can not find any reference to people actually using ~/lib.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this something that you've created yourself, or a third party installation?

Normally /usr/local/ is a good place to install packages not part of the original OS. I do this myself for anything I've built and installed from source. Another place to put things is /opt which is often used by commercial third party software.

If you're going to writing something of your own then using your home directory "~" sounds fine. This is also good if you don't have root access or don't want it to mixed in with the other OS packages.

When compiling and linking you will need to configure things to use those directories. Also if you're using dynamic shared libraries the LD_LIBRARY_PATH must be set as well.

Comment: I am working on a library of my own. Just want to make it easier to play with, like being able to write small programs "on the fly" without needing makefiles or long compilation commands. Thanks. I'll go with the home option.

Comment: I just realised that since I am using ~/bin for custom applications and scripts, ~/lib and ~/include look like a natural extension of this.